# Neo4j Client, how to retrieve node by id?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to figure out the way to retrieve node by id.

```
MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n) = {id} RETURN n
```

, is the Cypher I used with REST interface.
Now using fluent syntax of Neo4j Client for .net I cannot find the function name in Neo4J.Cypher namespace, like for instance ALL.
Anybody knows how to re-write that query in fluent syntax?

```
client.Cypher
.Match("(node:Employee)")
.Where(node=>**?**(node)== 3)
.Return(node)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `ID` function name in the codebase, so you have to go old skool I'm afraid - the code below still uses parameters...

```
client.Cypher
    .Match("(node:Employee)")
    .Where("ID(n) = {idParam}")
    .WithParam("idParam", 3)
    .Return(node => node.As<Employee>());
```