# How to use the neo4j graph algorithms with Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher, graph-algorithm, neo4jclient

I would like to use the [closeness centrality](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/algorithms/closeness-centrality/) graph algorithm with [Neo4jClient](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient) a .Net client for neo4j.

The query to use closeness centrality in Cypher is:

```
CALL algo.closeness.stream('Node', 'LINK')
YIELD nodeId, centrality

RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId).id AS node, centrality
ORDER BY centrality DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

My attempt at a translation to C#:

```
var clcsCent =
_graphClient.Cypher.Call("algo.closeness.stream('SitePoint', 'SEES')")
.Yield("node,centrality")
.Return((node,centrality)=>new {
Int32 = node.As<Int32>(),
Double = centrality.As<Double>()
})
.Results;
```

`SitePoint`is my class for nodes which have `SEES` relationships between them.

The exception I get is:

```
SyntaxException: Unknown procedure output: `node` (line 2, column 7 (offset: 
55))
"YIELD node,centrality"
        ^
```

What is the correct C# syntax for this query?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The Cypher query doesn't change with C# or any other programming language. Just find how to connect neo4j using C#

Comment: @Raj -  my question should have been clearer - I am using Neo4jClient a .Net client for neo4j. And belwood - also adding my initial attempt to translate the query. Editing the question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution - change 'node' for nodeId:

```
var clcsCent =
_graphClient.Cypher.Call("algo.closeness.stream('SitePoint', 'SEES')")
.Yield("nodeId,centrality")
.Return((nodeId,centrality)=>new {
Int32 = nodeId.As<Int32>(),
Double = centrality.As<Double>()
})
.Results;
```

This returns an IEnumerable where each element is an anonymous type with two properties for the nodeId and its centrality score.
Both `Int32 = nodeId.As<Int32>()` and `Double = centrality.As<Double>()` look like they should be more concise.

The [documentation for closeness centrality](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/3.5/algorithms/closeness-centrality/) gives 'node' as the name of the return type but it seems like it should be nodeId.

A useful resource for these cypher to C# translations is the [cypher examples page](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples) on the Neo4jClient github pages

Answer (score 0):

You are right this query returns `nodeId` instead of a `node`.

If you want node then your Cypher query should be like this

(I don't know how to translate this in C#, I think you can translate this to get the nodes):

```
CALL algo.closeness.stream('SitePoint', 'SEES')
YIELD nodeId, centrality
RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId) AS node, centrality
ORDER BY centrality DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: You may need another call in return to get the node from id in your existing C# translated code.

Comment: This is not exact what you need but may be some help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201777/neo4j-client-how-to-retrieve-node-by-id